# R Package for Optimal binning With Restrictions

Tags: r, binning

Does anyone know about a R Package like SMBinning that can make Optimal Binning for WoE analysis where you can impose restrictions like

- minimum x number of Target in each bin

  - monotome trend (WoE is either continues increasing of decreasing)
  - WoE trend is allowed to have one max or min (v or n shape)

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to switch to Python, the OptBinning library supports the restrictions you mentioned and more. OptBinning implements a rigorous and flexible mathematical programming formulation to solving the optimal binning problem for a binary, continuous, and multiclass target type.

https://github.com/guillermo-navas-palencia/optbinning

(Disclaimer: I am the author).